# Text Formatting

Tags: text, format

I need a bit of help with this one. So, I have a list which text is formatted like this:

```
bob@bob.com,Bob,Pitt,http://bobsite.com 
anna@anna.com,Ana,Pitt,http://annasite.com
john@john.com,John,Smith,http;//johnsite.com
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to copy every part individually, the e-mails i already did (with e-mail extractor), also i believe the link parts should be an easy job too. However, for the first and last name i simply can't find a way. A little help is much appreciated.

Comment: On what OS? What tools do you have available? E.g. this could easily be done with `awk` (or dozens of other tools)  It could also be done in `python` using the `csv` module, or in dozens of other languages. So you need to be more specific about your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do it programmatically or just looking for a tool? If you are looking for a programming solution, you could split each line by commas into each value you want.
A tool if you want to organize it differently would be to import the information as a CSV into Excel, Google Sheets, etc. They'll automatically separate everything into columns.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply.

Im not looking for a programmatically approach this issue. I'd like to organize them in separate columns in Excel, however when i paste them in Excel it puts them in 1 column. Also tried changing the file to .xls to make it open from Excel, it didnt work that as well.

Comment: Okay, i got it. changing the file type to .csv done the job. Thank you a lot Brett.